# Time format in xaxis of dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I need to x-axis to be formatted as like in this [example](http://dygraphs.com/tests/x-axis-formatter.html). 
my code

```
            axes: {
                  x: {
                    axisLabelFormatter: function(x) {
                      return moment(x,"HHmm").format("HH:mm");
                    }
                  }
```

am getting invalid date in x-axis while zooming.

Comment: this is the data 
10:59,1482,10

11:00,934,10

11:01,16,10
13:19,187,10
13:21,390,10
13:22,82,10
13:23,296,10

Comment: could you provide a demo via dygraphs.com/fiddle? it's hard to tell what the problem is from your question.

Comment: Hi, here the example in jsfiddle while you go zoom you will get invalid date http://jsfiddle.net/NtBPk/537/

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a roundoff issue.

```
> moment(12.6, 'HHmm').format('HH:mm')
"12:06"
> moment(12.600000000000001, 'HHmm').format('HH:mm')
"Invalid date"
```

According to the [moment docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), you're supposed to be passing it a string, not a number. It's likely that your numbers are being converted to strings and then parsed as dates, which is [risky business](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/03/javascript-and-dates-what-mess.html).

One immediate fix is to use `moment(Math.round(x))` in place of `moment(x)`, but there's still the deeper issue that you're still misusing the moment API.